# Apache poi 3.10 cannot read .xlsx files, can read .xls files. why is that?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
FileInputStream fis = null; //this will be used to read the excel file
fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
int numOfExcelRows = 0;

//create an excel workbook from the file system and check if is .xls or xlsx
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = null;
if (fileName.contains(".xls")){
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    numOfExcelRows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
}
else{        
    if (fileName.contains(".xlsx")){
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    numOfExcelRows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
}
```

Exactly the same problem here. This piece of code should work. Well it does, but for `.xls` files and not `.xlsx` files. No error produced, no exception, tried to save to different `.xlsx` formats nothing.
Any ideas? 
Anyone had the same issues and solved it?

well that is the weird thing.. that piece of code should work... i am starting to think its something with the library i am using either i am not specifying something correctly for it to work like : `Workbook workbook = new Workbook("C:\\book1.xlsx", loadOptions);`, or something is up.. i know its not working because it just gets stack at `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);` and my arrays do not get the values from .xlsx files, plus a simple print out to the console just comes up empty.. BUT no errors

Comment: If there's no error or exception, how do you know it doesn't work? What is happening (or not happening!) that should be (or should be)?

Comment: well that is the weird thing.. that piece of code should work... i am starting to think its something with the library i am using either i am not specifying something correctly for it to work like : Workbook workbook = new Workbook("C:\\book1.xlsx", loadOptions);, or something is up.. i know its not working because it just gets stack at XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); and my arrays do not get the values from .xlsx files, plus a simple print out to the console just comes up empty.. BUT no errors

Comment: Please add that info into the question itself. It's not possible to debug code without the problem.

Comment: Another possibility is that your `.xlsx` file is just a renamed `.xls` file?

Comment: yes my men exactly... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logic as you mentioned, once you find ".xls" (in both .xls and .xlsx file extensions), you've found your match, so .xlsx files match the first case too.  You can either logically check for .xlsx first, which would drop to .xls extensions naturally.  Or as @Arve suggested, let POI determine which file type(s) it finds for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `WorkbookFactory` instead, lets POI choose the right format.

See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

Ladies and Gents thank you for your time and consideration but i resolved the issues.
As always i was the one in error here.. the problem was logical : `fileName.contains(".xls")` well if you use contains and not contentEquals.. this is what u get... when i was trying to load a .xlsx file as you can see the if statement was true... and boom... :) well that's all folks ! 2 hours for this.. hehehe i love it :)